# Honda XL250R-C Carb ISSUES

Tags: honda, motorcycle, carburetor

I have a UK Honda XL250R-C 1982 pro link just purchased, I was told it had the wrong carb fitted which was a (PD70A) which is why it was running so bad, I was also given at the time of purchase a carb that is said to be the correct one (PD73AA) albeit in bits, could anyone please tell me what the correct carb should be for this bike before I start to refurbish the carb. 
Any help in this would be welcome.
Thanks,

Comment: Had a google and found a few parts diagrams. Oem part no: 16100-KB7-673

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: i got in touch with David Silver Honda, and he has confirmed it is the PD73A now purchased from eBay and revamped, still not fitted yet due to total refurbish so bike in bits, should be putting engine back in the bike in a couple of weeks then hopefully start it up